# "I would like that much."

Tags: word-usage

Why does the phrase "I would like that much," sound so much weirder than "I would like that very much?"

Is it incorrect to use *much* in this way without *very*, or is it just uncommon?

Comment: Hello, Jake. Have you done any searches to ascertain relative frequencies of usage?

Comment: Related Wordreference thread: [Negative Polarity Items (NPIs)](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/negative-polarity-items-npis.334277/) I think "much" without "very" in sentences of this type can also sound OK if there is a negation: "I wouldn't like that much" sounds a bit better to me than "I would like that much", although "I wouldn't like that very much" may be even better

Comment: @sumelic ... although the interrogative strangely seems to need re-ordering and is then very formal: 'Would you much like that?'

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer is:  *just because*.  While it's grammatically correct, it's something that people simply don't say, because it's one of those quirky things about English that defies explanation.  What you **can** say instead is, "I would like that a lot".